# How to get data of first column from table in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

How to get data of first column from table in django template

views.py

```py
    def get_table(request):
        table = Table.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'template.html', {'table': table})
```

template.html

```html
    {% block 'content' %}
        <h1 class="title">{{table|first.title}}</h1>
    {% endblock %}
```

But I'm getting

```bash
TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '.title' from 'table|first.title'
```

Database (db.sqlite3):

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Testing title |
| 2 | A really good title |

I have tried to put

```html
{% for data in table %}
    <h1 class="title">{{data.title}}</h1>
```

but that is not the case.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do that, for example using [`with`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#with):

```
{% block 'content' %}
 {% with data=table|first %}
    <h1 class="title">{{data.title}}</h1>
 {% endwith %}
{% endblock %}
```

Or you can use `{{table.first.title}}`, this [`first`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#first) is a queryset function.